# Index creation in Mongo

Tags: python, json, mongodb, indexing, pymongo

I have a dataset in the form:

```
{
  u'geometry': {
    u'type': u'Point',
    u'coordinates': [157.0625, -24.36573]
  },
  u'_id': ObjectId('5ad70f71f2119236741ffad6'),
  u'type': u'Feature',
  u'properties': {
    u'STATUS': u'8',
    u'TIMESTAMP': u'2013-12-31 17:03:00.000',
    u'MMSI': u'636015036',
    u'SPEED': u'98'
  }
}
```

I create a query that returns the positions (coordinates) of the ships grouped by MMSI and sorted. `Total`: the amount of records with the same MMSI, `COORDINATES`: the coordinates for the same MMSI gathered in an array and `_id`: the MMSI of the ship.

*Query (pymongo):*

```
getPositionsOfshipsgrouped = db.samplecol.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "properties.MMSI": { "$exists": "true" } } },
  {
    "$project": {
      "properties.MMSI": "$properties.MMSI",
      "geometry.coordinates": "$geometry.coordinates"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$properties.MMSI",
      "total": { "$sum": 1 },
      "COORDINATES": { "$push": "$geometry.coordinates" }
    }
  },
  { "$match": { "total": { "$gte": 0 } } },
  { "$sort": { "total": -1 } },
  { "$limit": 15 }
])
```

*Results:*

```
{
  u'total': 10,
  u'_id': u'503551000',
  u'COORDINATES': [
    [141.8705, -12.67311],
    [158.1707, -0.9142034],
    [157.1707, -0.9142034],
    [157.1707, -0.9142034],
    [157.1707, -0.9142034],
    [157.1707, -0.9142034],
    [159.1707, -0.8142034],
    [158.2707, -0.8142034],
    [159.1707, -0.8142034],
    [159.1707, -0.8142034]
  ]
}

{
  u'total': 2,
  u'_id': u'416243700',
  u'COORDINATES': [
    [159.1707, -0.8142034],
    [159.0707, -0.7142034]
  ]
}
```

I think that the creation of an index in a good idea here.
So first, I create a geospatial index in geometry:

```
db.samplecol.ensure_index([("geometry", "2dsphere")])
```

and then I create single keys indexes like:

```
db.samplecol.ensure_index([
  ("properties.MMSI", 1),
  ("geometry.coordinates", 1),
  ("properties.TIMESTAMP", 1)
])
```

I use in the index creation, the fields from from $project (in query above).

So my question is if these indexes creations will ensure a better performance and if the fields that I use are correct.
I have a small dataset and I don't see a better performance in terms of response time.

Comment: Sadly your aggregation pipeline in the question will not gain any performance benefit from the indexes. Is there some reason why you are using `$exists` on the first pipeline stage? I ask because getting rid of that and the following `$project` would in fact allow us to `$sort`, and that **"would"** have a performance impact. So ideally the `"properties.MMSI"` key should be in every document.

Comment: No, I can get rid of $exists field. "properties.MMSI" key exists in every field. So, without $exists this query with these indexes would have a performance impact?

Comment: As part of that, probably one of the harder things to come to terms with as opposed to something like SQL, is that the `$project` as "selection" here really is an **"anti-pattern"**. The `$group` actually already implies that the fields it references for output are in fact the only fields of the document that are required. And the query optimizer is smart enough to realize that, ***if** you don't get in it's way.

Comment: The `$exists` kills it really, as does the `$project`. Ideally this would `$sort,$group` and then the rest. But those two in combination at the beginning can actually select and process an index. As "covered" even if you had both of the properties in the same index. So I would contest that you don't need it, and then simply discard any `null` results from the grouping key. But it would be far more performant without the `null` values. Or maybe ["partial" indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/)

Comment: I change my query to this: getPositionsOfshipsgrouped =  db.samplecol.aggregate([{ "$group" : {"_id" : "$properties.MMSI", "total" : { "$sum" : 1 }, "COORDINATES": { "$push" :  "$geometry.coordinates" }   }},   { "$match" : { "total" : { "$gte" : 0 } } },   { "$sort" : {"total" : -1} }, { "$project" : {"properties.MMSI":"$properties.MMSI", "geometry.coordinates":"$geometry.coordinates"}},  { "$limit" : 15 }  ]). I see a small time reduction from 0.0010 to 0.0008. This is what you mean. Or i have to remove completely the $projection?